# Overwrite an inherited module's method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

I have this module

```
module MyModule
  def self.foo() 
    puts "A" 
  end
end
```

And this mixin class

```
class ParentClass
   include MyModule
    ...other code
end
```

Can I overwrite the `foo` method in a child class like this or is there a better way?

```
class ChildClass < ParentClass
   def self.foo() 
     puts "B" 
   end
   ... other code
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `include` class methods directly:

```
module MyModule
  def self.foo() puts "A" end
end

class ParentClass
   include MyModule
end
ParentClass.methods.include?(:foo)
  #=> false
ParentClass.instance_methods.include?(:foo)
  #=> false
```

Instead, use [Object#extend](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-extend), which converts instance methods in `MyModule` to class methods in `ParentClass`:

```
module MyModule
  def foo() puts "A" end
end

class ParentClass
   extend MyModule
end
ParentClass.methods.include?(:foo)
  #=> true
ParentClass.foo
A

class ChildClass < ParentClass
  def self.foo() puts "B" end
end     
ChildClass.foo
B
```

So, you may ask, what's the point of having class methods in a module? They can be present when the module is not used as a mixin, or has a combination of instance and class methods. The module's class methods are simply helper functions:

```
module A
  def self.say
    puts "It's a cat."
  end
  def say
    puts "It's a dog."
  end        
end

class B
  include A
end

A.say
It's a cat

B.new.say
It's a dog.
```

It is my impression that most modules that contain class methods tend to contain no instance methods; that is, they are not used as mix-ins. Readers are encouraged to correct me if I am wrong about that.

A common way to `include` some instance methods and `extend` others is to use the callback [Module#included](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Module.html#method-i-included):

```
module A
  def a; end
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend B
  end
  module B
    def b; end
  end
end

class C
  include A
end

C.instance_methods.include?(:a)
  #=> true
C.methods.include?(:b)
  #=> true
```

Comment: Thanks for the enlightment